# I am always getting the error "address already in use :::3000"

Tags: server, nodejs, npm, javascript

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1280:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1328:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1415:7)

Comment: you already have a process listening at port 3000.  Whatever you're trying to run/use is already bound to port 3000 or something else is bound there and it can't start up properly because port 3000 is in use.  What exactly are you doing that *causes* this error?  What program are you running, etc.?

Comment: You can also do `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` to see which apps are listening at which ports.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `fuser 3000/tcp` to get the pid of the process running on that port. 
After that run `ls -l /proc/<PID>/exe` to get some process details. 
Use it's output to determine whether you want to kill that process or start your service on a different port ( imo I would recommend the 2nd option).

Comment: think you missed the proper mark for the port - `300` is not `3000`.  also what you've stated isn't an answer more a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed nodejs in your system,
Open terminal and type the following command to kill the process on a port

Syntax: `npx kill-port <port-number>`

Example

```
npx kill-port 3000
```

Comment: thanks it worked